# Post data in djangon api and unable to get variable value

Tags: python, django

I have created a api which i am sending request by post but didn't get vairable in a view

```
def login_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.dumps(request.POST)
        print(data)
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        #print(serializer)
        return JsonResponse({"message":'fdsafdsa'})
```

when i print data **print(data)** then out put is coming like this

```
{"{\"login\":122122,\"abvc\":\"544545\"}": ""}
```

and i calling this api like this in postman

```
Post http://localhost:8000/login/login/

{"login":122122,"abvc":"544545"}
```

I am not geting value with this

print(request.POST['login']);

how can i get value

Comment: "how can i assign login variable value in a variable?" what does that mean?

Comment: i want to print login variable value

Comment: request.POST['login'] this is not working

Comment: define not working

Comment: Why would you think it should work?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please let me know how it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `request.data` instead of `request.POST`. JSON Content is sent in body, which is parsed by Django Rest Framework at runtime.

```
login_variable = request.data['login']
```

And ensure you have added 'JSONParser' in REST_FRAMEWORK settings.

Comment: Have you added JSONParser in your rest framework settings

Comment: MultiValueDictKeyError at /login/login/ "'login'"

Comment: {"detail":"Unsupported media type \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" in request."} after add   rest framework settings JSONParser

Comment: Send 'Content-Type': 'application/json' headers in your request

Comment: Thanks @hspandher

Comment: Any time. My pleasure